# Must -read articles for C++ memory mangement

Tags: c++

After reading "[C++ Memory Management: From Fear to Triumph](http://linuxdevcenter.com/lpt/a/3658)" series,  I think they are  must-read articles for memory management. I'd like to know what else must-read articles I shouldn't miss.

Thanks!

Comment: To add to Mark's comment, some questions (such as polls, lists and this one) don't allow for a single, correct answer that you can to accept. Such questions should be made community wiki (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1320/what-are-the-guidelines-for-community-wiki-on-meta-stack-overflow). This isn't to say that community wiki questions can't have accepted answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read and learn well about [RAII](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/RAII) idiom, [Resource Acquisition Is Initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) from articles like the two below:

- [Memory and Resource Management by Stephen C. Dewhurst](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30642&seqNum=8)
- [Resource Acquisition is Initialization](http://www.artima.com/intv/modern3.html) - Modern C++ Style - A Conversation with Bjarne Stroustrup, Part II

Answer (score 4):

Herb sutter's treatment on Memory Management in his books "Exceptional C++" and "More Exceptional C++".

Comment: @Charles, No it is Herb Sutter. I think Scott Meyer's Effective C++ series also has memory management related items. But, not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Although not really an article, I think the [Boost smart_ptr library documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm)  has some good information on C++ memory management. It is of course biased to the Boost library but I think you will get some good ideas out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Some basics:

Memory as a Programming Concept in C and C++

Frantisek Franek

Cambridge University Press

ISBN 0-521-52043-6

Answer (score 0):

Andrei Alexandrescu has also something to say in his [Modern C++ Design](http://www.awl.com/cseng/titles/0-201-70431-5/) Book.
You'd probably interested in

- Chapter 4. Small-Object Allocation
- Chapter 7. Smart Pointers

Despite the fact that practical value of Andrei's techniques considered controversial, you definitely will learn some new and interesting stuff from this book.

Comment: Considered controversial? By who, and why?

Comment: It's criticized by C++ community (some part of, not by me) for using unnecessary "clever" techniques.

Answer (score 0):

More than a decade passed since the original question, but us, C++ developers still not a master of memory management.

Google recently published an [article](https://research.google/pubs/secure-by-design-googles-perspective-on-memory-safety/) about memory safety. It lists some approaches that can help make an existing codebase safer.

For example,

> Enforcing
> definite initialization or disallowing pointer arithmetic

> Similarly, adding lifetimes to C++ will improve interoperability

Also mentions two interesting ideas, [MTE](https://newsroom.arm.com/memory-safety-arm-memory-tagging-extension) (Memory tagging extension) and [CHERI](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/security/ctsrd/cheri/) (Capability Hardware Enhanced RISC Instructions).